# Flashlight Shake to Switch On

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a flashlight project on xcode but i cant figure out how to add brightness control to it..I have buttons which are hidden for the on and off part of the flashlight and im using imageviews to display prerendered images. Im posting my code below, all help will be appreciated thanks.

```
Viewcontroller.h-  
is basically the initializations of the buttons, IBActions, IBOutlets and Properties


ViewController.m



#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize offButton,onview,onButton,offview,slider;

-(IBAction)torchon:(id)sender
{

    onButton.hidden=YES;
    offButton.hidden=NO;
    onview.hidden=NO;
    offview.hidden=YES;


    AVCaptureDevice *device=[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if([device isTorchAvailable]&&[device isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
    {
        BOOL sucessful=[device  lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if(sucessful)
        {
            [device  setTorchModeOnWithLevel:slider.value error:NULL];

            [device  unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}

-(IBAction)torchoff:(id)sender
{
    AVCaptureDevice *flashlight=[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if([flashlight isTorchAvailable]&&[flashlight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
    {
        BOOL sucessful=[flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if(sucessful)
        {
            [flashlight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];

            [flashlight unlockForConfiguration];

        }
    }

    onButton.hidden=NO;
    offButton.hidden=YES;
    onview.hidden=YES;
    offview.hidden=NO;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    onButton.hidden=YES;
    offButton.hidden=NO;
    onview.hidden=NO;
    offview.hidden=YES;
    AVCaptureDevice *device =[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if([device  isTorchAvailable]&&[device  isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
    {
        BOOL sucessful=[device  lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if(sucessful)
        {
            [device  setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];

            [device  unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
-(IBAction)slideing:(id)sender
{
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0f;
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    [slider setContinuous:YES];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:slider.value error:NULL];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];


}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated

}
@end



and nothing in appdelegate.m and appdelegate.h

i have created my objects like a slider, and button as well as the image views in a storyboard and have linked them to my code. I've used IBAction functions and have used interface builder a bit as well. As i said before, i cant figure out how to add a shake to switch on and off feature. Any help is appreciated!
```

Comment: Good idea bad timing. iOS 7 will have a built in flashlight, so you may need to think about something else to build.

Comment: Aw shucks. thanks anyway